# How can I apply custom styles to the mat-menu content?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

I use the mat-menu for filtering the columns in the custom table component. In the mat-menu I have a search input which I want to style.
I have tried:

```
class
panelClass
backdropClass
```

but with no success. I want to point out that if I put the styles in the main style.scss file the css is applied to the input field. But I want to solve it in another way, putting the css in the components file.
Here is my code:

```
<mat-menu #menu>
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlex="100">
      <div stop-propagation fxFlex="90" fxFlexOffset="5">
        <div class="input-container">
          <input id="inputSearch" class="search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="{{ 'Ricerca...' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (keyup)="filterValue(col.key)">
        </div>
        <mat-selection-list class="selectList" #select [id]="col.key"
          (selectionChange)="selecteChange($event, col.key)" class="maxHeight300">
          <ng-container *ngIf="conditionsList && conditionsList.length > 0; else noOptions">
            <mat-list-option color="primary" [checkboxPosition]="'before'" *ngFor="let condition of conditionsList"
              [value]="condition">
              {{ condition }}
            </mat-list-option>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #noOptions>
            <span fxLayoutAlign="center center" [innerHTML]="'Nessun risultato' | translate"></span>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-selection-list>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="90" fxFlexOffset="5" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center"
        *ngIf="conditionsList && conditionsList.length > 0" class="marginBottom10">
        <button fxFlex="49" mat-raised-button (click)="clearColumn(col.key)">Pulisci</button>
        <button fxFlex="49" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="applyFilter(col.key)">Filtra</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-menu>
```

and the css

```
.search-input {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, -webkit-box-shadow 0.3s;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0px 2px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);      
}
```

Comment: You could use `::ng-deep .search-input` or use `ViewEncapsulation.None` to keep the style in the file for the component, but in the end the effect is the same - the styles are promoted to the global level, meaning they COULD affect other components.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I want to avoid, beside I have already tried it and it doesn't work. Thanks for the comment

Comment: There's no way around it though - this is because of how the mat-menu (and CdkOverlay in general) is instantiated. It's scoped in different part of the application than your component, so there is no way for your styles to affect it unless they are scoped globally (in one way or the other) as well. Regarding the "not working" part - can you be more specific? This is a quick repro of it working using `ng-deep`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byqztx

Comment: I reproduced your example again using ` ::ng-deep .pClass { .search-input {...}}` and has no effect on the input field, I am not sure why though

Comment: Try creating a proper repro on stackblitz then. It seems to be working perfectly fine for me, so it's probably something else in your app. I've edited the existing stackblitz repo to include an input and style it using your styles: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byqztx

Comment: yess it worksss, put it as an answer, I will mark it solved. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments from question:

Due to how MatMenu (and CdkOverlay in general, which is used underneath) is instantiated, styles have to be scoped globally for them to affect things rendered in the overlay. They can be placed in different file, but they have to pierce the component level in some way.

This means that one can style it with one of the below:

- Use `::ng-deep` (which is deprecated, but still working) selector to pierce the component
- Use `ViewEncapsulation.None` to promote the component stylesheet to the global level
- Place styles in the global styles.scss

An example using `::ng-deep` with styles from the question are provided in  the [stacblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byqztx).